# Laravel multiple where AND conditions not working

Tags: laravel

I want to sort the car product details by the below query. But it returns an empty array. Please help me.

```
public function fetchall($min_price, $max_price, $milage, $old_year, $new_year, $carbrand)
{
$cars = Cars::where([
            ['price','>=',$min_price],
            ['price','<=',$max_price],
            ['year','>=',$old_year],
            ['year','<=',$new_year],
            ['milage','=', $milage],
            ['model_id','=', $carbrand]])->get();

if (!empty($cars)) {
     return $cars;
} else {
     return "Check your details and submit again";
}
```

Comment: According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) your statement looks OK. I'd say your values are invalid or there simply are no matching records in the database.

Comment: Can you post the entire function.

Comment: I added the function. Please check once

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `!empty($cars)` use `!$cars->isEmpty()`.

---

`$cars` is an object of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` so `empty()` won't work.

See [Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods) for `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.